# Sort a list of different objects by a common property

Tags: c#, .net, sorting, object

I have a `List<object>` that contains instances of three types `GuestbookEntry`, `Comment` and `SectionEntry`. Those three classes have a common `CreateDate` property.

Is there any way that I am able to sort this list on a given property (which I know all the objects have) without knowing the type of the object?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you can't make those two classes derive from a common `Interface`\ `Base Class` Which is the best Object Oriented solution.
You can cast the the list items to dynamic.

```
List<object> list = GetListFromSomeWhere();
var dynamicList = list.Cast<dynamic>();
```

Then sort the dynamic list without compilation errors:

```
dynamicList.OrderBy(x => x.CreateDate);
```

Comment: gdoron, that's just awesome :) Can't believe I never thinked about using the dynamic type - guess I'm still stuck in .net 3.5, hehe ;) Thank you!

Comment: I guess we should add .ToList() at the end of the list.Cast<dynamic>() because otherwise it shows error?